# C++ Sorting numbers in arrays

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am trying to get this out put:

- 1 10
- 2 9
- 3 8
- 4 7
- 5 6

How do I do that?

My code:

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        const int n=10;
        int Tab[n]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    
    
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            for(int j=5; j>=0; j--)
                cout << Tab[i] << " " << Tab[j] << endl;
    
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Your array is already sorted, so there's no need to sort it again.

Comment: isn't it 2 9, 3 8, 4 7, 5 6

Comment: Yes because in your suggested output you skip 9 but it is not clear why

Comment: @Slava I made mistake. My bad.

Comment: @JaredPL What is output if the number of elements is odd?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie already answered that ;oP

Comment: A literal answer to your question if `std::cout << "1 10\n2 9\n3 8\n4 7\n5 6";`. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are trying to do and what exactly is preventing you from doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I do that?

You do not need 2 loops, you just use one loop and calculate second index:

```
    for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++) 
        cout << Tab[i] << " " << Tab[n-i-1] << endl;
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/idJ58m)

PS in this form for array with odd number of elements it will skip middle one. If you want it to be printed twice instead, change loop condition to this:

```
    for(int i=0; i<(n+1)/2; i++)
```

for even elements it will work as before.

Comment: *1 0
    *2 10
    *3 10
    *4 9
    *5 8

Comment: Made mistake, it should be `-1` not `+1`, now it is fixed see live example

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

1. You need to iterate all the elements of the array. So for loop condition should be i<(length of array).
2. There are multiple sorting algorithms to sort an array and in each of these algos you need to compare the element you are processing with other elements to decide its location in final array.

pseudo code should look like

```
first for loop
    second for loop 
      if element ith  > element jth   //assuming you wanted to sort in ascending format
         swap(element i and j)
```

I am not sharing full code since it seems like a homework problem and I suggest you should try to solve yourself.

If you see any other issue. Please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort your array, you can use std::sort function. This function works on array or vector. Yours is array.
Two arguments are required: the beginning of the array and the length n up to which you want the array to be sorted.
Example

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 5, 8, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
 
    sort(arr, arr + n);
 
    cout << "\nArray after sorting ";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
 
    return 0;
}
```

This will sort in ascending order. You can add one more argument to sort in descending order:

sort(arr, arr + n, greater());